# String aggregation in pandas, unique values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long table like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'prod_id':[1011, 1012, 1011, 2090, 2090, 2090]})
```

I'd like to aggregate on customer id cus_id and get a list if product ids they have purchased and record it as string dtype. Such as

| cus_id | prod_ids_agg |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | '1011, 1012' |
| 2 | '2090' |

While I have solved this as follows, I don't think that is the best practice. Do you have any suggestions for making this code better?

```
def strl(s):
    abc = ''
    for item in s:
        if item != s[0]:
            abc = abc + ', ' + str(item)
        else: 
            abc = abc + str(item)
    return str(abc)

df  = sql_result[['cus_id', 'prod_id']].copy()    

df_grpd = df.groupby('cus_id')

dfs = df_grpd['prod_id'].apply(lambda x: strl(list(np.unique(x)))).reset_index()

dfs
```

I want to add another column with number of unique prod_ids but I am lost on doing that in the same dataframe. How can I do it the simple way?

| cus_id | prod_ids_agg | prod_ids_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | '1011, 1012' | 2 |
| 2 | '2090' | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

```py
df.groupby(['cus_id'])['prod_id'].agg(prod_ids_agg = 'unique', count='nunique')
```

```
        prod_ids_agg    count
cus_id      
1       [1011, 1012]    2
2       [2090]          1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be use to custom function with `groupby` -

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'cus_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],'prod_id':[1011, 1012, 1011, 2090, 2090, 2090]})


def agg_prod_id(inp,group_col=['cus_id'],agg_column='prod_id'):

    agg_val = ','.join(map(str,inp.loc[:,agg_column].unique()))
    final_columns = group_col + [ agg_column ]

    group_vals = []

    for col in group_col:
        group_vals += [inp.loc[:,col].values[0]]

    data = group_vals + [ agg_val ]

    temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[data],columns=final_columns)

    return temp


df_agg = df.groupby('cus_id').apply(lambda x : agg_prod_id(x)).reset_index(drop=True)

print(df_agg)

  cus_id    prod_id
0       1  1011,1012
1       2       2090
```